# Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine'

Tags: c#, wcf

I create a simple wcf project with authentication method with this config as you  can see :

```
        <serviceCertificate findValue="STSTestCert"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                            storeName="My"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

but when i run the project i get this error :

Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue 'STSTestCert'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue 'STSTestCert'.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the certificate is installed? Example, if you try in PowerShell `dir cert:\LocalMachine\My`, do you find the certificate `STSTestCert` there? If not then you probably installed it somewhere else. Perhaps when you've installed it you have not explicitly specified the `Personal` folder (because this is what `My` means here)